# What do I need to be able to "dock/tile" windows side by side

Tags: window-management

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 (Command Line System via Alternate CD) then packages I need including `ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends`. I find that I can't tile windows side by side by dragging a window to the side anymore. I guess I'm missing a package?

**UPDATE**: I am Ubuntu Classic so not using Unity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be missing [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager)  if you use Unity/Compiz.

And then have a look at the `snap` plugin.

- **Snap Type** Here you can define what types of snapping are available.

  - Checking Edge Resistance makes windows snap to edges and you must move the mouse further before they un-snap
  - Checking Edge Attraction makes windows snap to edges as you get close to them
- **Edges** allows you to define what is an edge

  - Checking Screen Edges makes windows snap to the edges of your screen
  - Checking Window Edges makes windows snap to the edges of other windows
- The value Edge Resistance Distance defines how many pixels space you must move your mouse before the window un-snaps
- The value Edge Attraction Distance defines how many pixels space windows must be next to each other before they snap.

Comment: I updated my post. I am not using Unity but Ubuntu Classic

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm going to give you rep for still trying anyways, even though it doesn't fully apply! Good job Rinzwind!

Comment: Thanks :D But what about Marko? >:-)

Answer (score 0):

For this I mostly use Xtile gnome applet to do what you want. You can get it [here](http://www.giuspen.com/x-tile/)

Compiz plugins are good but I don't run Compiz on most of my machines.